CakePHP Limit Total Page Count
Say I've got 1000 records in a table.
I want to display 50 of said records (which are ordered in a specific way by my query).  I want say 10 per page, with a maximum total records of 50, so 5 total pages of records.
How can I do this?
I've seen the limit and maxLimit paginate properties, but those limit the 'perPage' records, not 'total' records like the sql LIMIT of a $query->limit(50) of a non-paginated query.
I'm on CakePHP 4.3
